# <script> or <noscript>?

Tags: noscript

i just wonder what's the better solution.

I have an iFrame with a google map on my website. the iframe has an id="map".
I wonder now what's the better solution if I don't want the map to show if javascript is turned off.

should I have a

```
<noscript> <style type="text/css"> #map {display:none) </style> </noscript>
```

or can I wrap the whole iFrame inside of a  **iFrame**  to make sure it does just show up if js is turned on.

thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `display: none` the **default** for the #map container. In the Javascript that is responsible for constructing the map, the first thing you do is to switch it to `display: block`.

But is this really necessary? Usually your #map container should only be an empty placeholder anyway, which simply won't get populated if Javascript is not available.